# If checkbox checket = true, put "X" to the appropriate cell in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have WinForm app with multiple checkbox (e.g. 5 checkboxes), two textboxes and datagridview with 8 column. I would like my application to put the value of `Textbox1` to second column, value of `Textbox2` to third column in data Gridview and when e.g `Checkbox1.Checked=true` then fourth column of datagridview will contain `"X"`. If Gridview and when e.g `Checkbox1.Checked=true` then fourth column of datagridview will contain `""`. I would like this to apply to all checkboxes.

Here is an example:

[image]

I was able to add values from the textboxes, but I don't know what to do next.

```vb
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim name, surname As String

        name = TextBox1.Text
        surname = TextBox2.Text


        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {CStr(DataGridView1.RowCount), name, surname})
        Me.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1

    End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: why do you need X if you can have checkbox column. Bind your datasource to the grid and to the controls - problem solved

Comment: Thanks for the quick advice,
Later I would like to export the contents of the datagrid to a text file
I believe that the result of the checkbox in the datagrid will not be recognizable in the text document

Comment: it will be `true` or `false`.

Comment: Oki, I try it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with follow method:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim name, surname As String
    Dim index As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount + Me.DataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex
    name = TextBox1.Text
    surname = TextBox2.Text

    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String() {CStr(DataGridView1.RowCount), name, surname})
    DataGridView1.Rows(index - 1).Cells(3).Value = CheckBox1.CheckState
    DataGridView1.Rows(index - 1).Cells(4).Value = CheckBox2.CheckState
    DataGridView1.Rows(index - 1).Cells(5).Value = CheckBox3.CheckState
    DataGridView1.Rows(index - 1).Cells(6).Value = CheckBox4.CheckState
    DataGridView1.Rows(index - 1).Cells(7).Value = CheckBox5.CheckState


    CheckBox1.Checked = False
    CheckBox2.Checked = False
    CheckBox3.Checked = False
    CheckBox4.Checked = False
    CheckBox5.Checked = False

End Sub
```

But when I try to export Contents of datagritview, I have error. For export to .txt I use this code:

```
Private Sub export(export As String)
    Dim zlozka As String

    zlozka = "C:\EX\GUARD\skuska.csv"

    Dim thecsvfile As String = String.Empty
    For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
        thecsvfile = thecsvfile & ","
    Next
    thecsvfile = thecsvfile.TrimEnd(CChar(","))
    thecsvfile = thecsvfile & vbCr & vbLf
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            thecsvfile = thecsvfile & cell.FormattedValue.replace(",", ",") & ","
        Next
        thecsvfile = thecsvfile.TrimEnd(CChar(","))
        thecsvfile = thecsvfile & vbCr & vbLf
    Next
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(zlozka, thecsvfile, False)

End Sub
```

Here is picture of error:
[image]

Thank you for help